# GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails (NVP) Missing Fields

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-nvp

The `GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails` call is not returning all of the fields it's supposed to according to the [API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails_API_Operation_NVP/).

This is an example request:

```
(
    [USER] => paypal_api1.xxx.com
    [PWD] => AY6Z6HNXXXX
    [SIGNATURE] => AdehadoDswh-XXXXXXnjPNEgmAFl20HyV7tFQZoL4
    [VERSION] => 64
    [METHOD] => GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails
    [PROFILEID] => I-XXXXXXX
)
```

This is the response:

```
(
    [PROFILEID] => I-CL7Kxxx
    [STATUS] => Active
    [AUTOBILLOUTAMT] => AddToNextBilling
    [DESC] => xxx
    [MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS] => 2
    [SUBSCRIBERNAME] => Dan
    [PROFILESTARTDATE] => 2013-05-15T07:00:00Z
    [PROFILEREFERENCE] => 31571
    [NEXTBILLINGDATE] => 2013-05-16T10:00:00Z
    [NUMCYCLESCOMPLETED] => 1
    [NUMCYCLESREMAINING] => 18446744073709551615
    [OUTSTANDINGBALANCE] => 0.00
    [FAILEDPAYMENTCOUNT] => 0
    [LASTPAYMENTDATE] => 2013-05-15T14:52:04Z
    [LASTPAYMENTAMT] => 0.10
    [TRIALAMTPAID] => 0.00
    [REGULARAMTPAID] => 0.10
    [AGGREGATEAMT] => 0.10
    [AGGREGATEOPTIONALAMT] => 0.00
    [FINALPAYMENTDUEDATE] => 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2013-05-15T14:55:58Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 225681xxx
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 64
    [BUILD] => 5908853
    [SHIPTOSTREET] => xxx
    [SHIPTOCITY] => xxx
    [SHIPTOSTATE] => CA
    [SHIPTOZIP] => xxx
    [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => US
    [SHIPTOCOUNTRY] => US
    [SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME] => United States
    [SHIPADDRESSOWNER] => PayPal
    [SHIPADDRESSSTATUS] => Unconfirmed
    [BILLINGPERIOD] => Day
    [BILLINGFREQUENCY] => 1
    [TOTALBILLINGCYCLES] => 0
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [AMT] => 0.10
    [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
    [TAXAMT] => 0.00
    [REGULARBILLINGPERIOD] => Day
    [REGULARBILLINGFREQUENCY] => 1
    [REGULARTOTALBILLINGCYCLES] => 0
    [REGULARCURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [REGULARAMT] => 0.10
    [REGULARSHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
    [REGULARTAXAMT] => 0.00
)
```

Now according to the API I should be receiving these fields (amongst others):

- EMAIL
- FIRSTNAME
- LASTNAME

I've tried just about everything I could think of to get the above information without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just received a comment from PayPal saying this bug has been resolved.

> We appreciate your patience. This message is to inform you that the issue was **resolved through a recent live site update**.
>
> ...
>
> PayPal Merchant Technical Services

Answer (score 0):

Was this information initially passed over?  Does it show on the profile, make sure you initially passed it over.  They will not be returned if they are not passed over.  I just ran a test, and I received these fields back when making the API call for the details.

Comment: The method I'm using is `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` which contains the user's email address that's in our system, also passed is the token returned after returning from offsite.

Is this because we're using Paypal Standard to create the payment profile? What was your test?

Comment: I originally tested with creating a profile using a credit card, not Express Checkout.  I went back and ran another test creating a profile from a token, and you are correct no email, first name, or last name is returned.  I would suggest opening up a ticket with MTS at www.paypal.com/mts.  This way you will be notified once this issue has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Reference #130518-000121

Comment: I will get the bug filed with our engineers and update you through the ticket you opened up once the issue is resolved.